# Is there any LIDAR 3D perception package for ROS2?

Tags: ros2, lidar

I spent a very long time searching GitHub, Google, and many other sites, looking for a LiDAR recognition package for ROS2, but I could only find one nvidia pointpillar model.
Because it requires a lot of dependency and high computing power, it is hard to use.
IS there anyone who know any classic clustering-based models, Apollo models, or other ROS2 packages, I'd appreciate it if you could share them.